# Passing a parameter into a slurm script (matlab)

Tags: matlab, parameters, slurm, sbatch

I am using slurm to submit jobs to the university supercomputer. My matlab function has one parameter:

function test(variable_1)

and my slurm file is (I am not sure if it is correct. I know how to define the value of the parameter in the slurm file, but I would like to pass the value to the slurm file as I need to run the matlab function many times with different values for the parameter):

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH --time=2-00:00:00

#SBATCH --job-name="test"

#SBATCH --nodes=1

#SBATCH --ntasks=1

#SBATCH --mem=4gb

#SBATCH -p small

module load matlab/R2021a

matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r "test variable_1"
```

I tried to use the following codes (for example, I would like to set variable_1=12) to submit the job but it did not work.

```
sbatch  test.slurm 12
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You should be using `matlab -batch "test variable_1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of the Bash script is stored in an environment variable named `$1`. So the last line of the script should be

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nosplash -r "test $1"
```

Beware that if the argument is a number, you might need to first cast it to integer from string with `str2num` in your Matlab script.

Comment: The last part makes no sense. The string is evaluated, and using the command format for calling a function, all arguments are passed in as strings.